No tx builder in Safe Wallet Web UI
Cannot resolve my issue by other similar questions, so I ask a new question.
When I go Transaction Builder page, its nothing, just white space.

versions

CFG_VERSION: safeglobal/safe-config-service:v2.87.0
CGW_VERSION: safeglobal/safe-client-gateway:v3.53.0
TXS_VERSION: safeglobal/safe-transaction-service:v5.10.0
UI_VERSION: safeglobal/safe-wallet-web:v1.44.2
EVENTS_VERSION: safeglobal/safe-events-service:v0.12.0

Our UI link https://safe.meter.io/
Safe Tx Builder app: https://apps-portal.safe.global/tx-builder/
-- Is there some I have to do for resolve it?

The follow is our cfg
PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=true

SECRET_KEY=insecure_key_for_dev

DEBUG=true
ROOT_LOG_LEVEL=DEBUG

DJANGO_ALLOWED_HOSTS="*"

GUNICORN_BIND_PORT=8001

DOCKER_NGINX_VOLUME_ROOT=/nginx

GUNICORN_BIND_SOCKET=unix:${DOCKER_NGINX_VOLUME_ROOT}/gunicorn.socket

# NGINX_HOST_PORT=8080

NGINX_ENVSUBST_OUTPUT_DIR=/etc/nginx/

POSTGRES_USER=postgres
POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
POSTGRES_NAME=postgres
POSTGRES_HOST=cfg-db
POSTGRES_PORT=5432

DOCKER_WEB_VOLUME=.:/app

GUNICORN_WEB_RELOAD=false

DJANGO_SUPERUSER_PASSWORD=***
DJANGO_SUPERUSER_USERNAME=root
DJANGO_SUPERUSER_EMAIL=test@example.com
DJANGO_OTP_ADMIN=false

DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE=django.core.files.storage.FileSystemStorage

FORCE_SCRIPT_NAME=/cfg/

CGW_URL=https://safe.meter.io/cgw
CGW_AUTH_TOKEN=meter_random_token

CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS="https://safe.meter.io"

MEDIA_URL=/media/
MEDIA_ROOT=/app/media

PUSH_NOTIFICATIONS_API_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_CLIENT_EMAIL=test@example.com

and the tx builder I just use the https://apps-portal.safe.global/tx-builder/ directly


Could you check it for me please? thanks.


A few leads could explain why it is not working on your end:

Have you run this repo https://github.com/safe-global/safe-react-apps/tree/development/apps/tx-builder, and added it to your configuration with Add custom safe apps;
Did you enable safe apps within your config service?

Please let me know if that solved the issue 
Best, Louis

Could you have a check on my config? thank u

It's worked, SAFE_APPS in features is necessary. thanks

Thanks for letting us know  Would you be OK to mark the question as solved if that solved the issue? Thank you in advance. Best, Louis
